# Samsung galaxy note 5 viewport size

Tags: android, css, media-queries, samsung-galaxy

I have some trouble replicating a website responsive issue using Samsung Note 5. The display is messed up when using the said device. I tried using chrome dev tool and adjust sizes for a chance to replicate it but no luck. I also search the internet but I can't see note 5 viewport size.

I tried `360x640` but it displays with no issues so I think this is not the right viewport for the Note 5. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _it displays with no issues so I think this is not the right viewport_ how it be?

Comment: @SagarV, yes is it's the right viewport then it will respond to my query. This issue appears using fixed and absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Add some screenshot as well as the styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to statistics

```
Pixel size: 1440 x 2560
ViewPort size: 480 x 853
```

Also you can get this information with javascript:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this site](http://responsivechecker.net/device/galaxy-note-5)

```
Screen Size (X - Horizontally): 1440

Screen Size (Y - Vertically): 2560

Pixel Ratio: 4.0
```

Portrait

It is 360 x 640

The site also allow you to enter any URL and render it in a virtual galaxy note 5

## Side Note

The material design project have a web directory in which they listed the display details of many well known mobile phones

## Alternate Site

[This site](http://www.viewportemulator.com/devices/samsung/galaxy-s5-sm-g900f/) also allow you to render a url into a virtual galaxy note 5

---

<sub>*Disclosure affiliation : I am in no way affiliated with any of the sites and also not an official representative of it/them*</sub>

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information. I tried `360 x 640` but the result is not what I expected. The responsive site tester is great though but for some reason, it won't render the site.

Comment: @claudios what is the url?

Comment: sorry but the site is confidential. Tried it but I wonder why it won't render. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
Samsung Galaxy Note 5
screen size: 1440 x 2560
viewport: 480 x 853
```

Comment: Hey! I tested it and it seems working. I'll get back after testing.

Comment: I think it should be `400 x 700`